# Override Tomcat Default on Startup

Tags: tomcat, configuration

I currently configure my Ant builds to have a `deploy-local` target that creates a WAR of my web application, and then simply copies that WAR file to my local Tomcat's `webapps/` directory.

The problem is, every time I run Tomcat, it first unpacks all the WARs in its `webapps/` directory into folders, thus `MyWebApp.war` gets unpacked to a directory called `MyWebApp/` before Tomcat finishes starting up.

It is obvious that Tomcat is then deploying out of that copied directory (not my WAR). I have proven this by stopping Tomcat, deleting the WAR (but leaving the copied directory in tact), and then restarting Tomcat...it works!

The huge pain-in-the-neck here is that every time I tweak my projects and run `deploy-local` to test them, I have to first manually delete the copied directory in `webapps/` (otherwise Tomcat will ignore the new WAR file copied over from Ant, and instead just deploys from the old copied directory!).

This has become extremely annoying! I've spoken with my tech lead about this and he doesn't seem to have the same problem (both of us are using Tomcat **7.0.19**). Furthermore, the Tomcat instances we have running in Dev, QA and Production don't suffer from this either. This tells me its a configuration issue on my end.

Please advise!!! And thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem, as i checked the source code of tomcat, then i found that it does have this bug. the official document says that tomcat will check newer war associated with the direcoty, but it does not work actually.

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete the directory using ant and allow Tomcat to automatically deploy the new webapp by putting this in your build.xml:

```
<target name="deploy" depends="war" description="Deployment target.">
    <delete dir="${tomcat.home.dir}/webapps/MYWEBAPP"/>
    <delete file="${tomcat.home.dir}/webapps/MYWEBAPP.war"/>
    <copy file="${build.dir}/MYWEBAPP.war" todir="${tomcat.home.dir}/webapps"/>
</target>
```

Running `ant deploy` in this case would do the trick.

Alternatively, run Tomcat and your webapp from inside Eclipse, which provides the option to Serve modules without publishing (meaning the Eclipse project runs directly without even needing to build a WAR).

I'm not aware of a way to get Tomcat to run a WAR without extracting it.